# How do I DumpLive results of a long running process?

Tags: system.reactive, linqpad

I've tried [`Observable.Create`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16971602/57883)

waits to finish before showing any results.
Possibly because the example I'm trying to follow is a changing live value, not a changing live collection.

and

`ObservableCollection<FileAnalysisResult> fileAnalysisResults = new ObservableCollection<FileAnalysisResult>();`

I can't seem to apply because `.DumpLive()` isn't applicable to an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: This is probably because the observable is running on the calling thread. Try adding `.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: use LINQPad's `DumpContainer`:

```
var dc = new DumpContainer().Dump();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    dc.Content = i;
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

**Long answer**: `DumpContainer` writes to LINQPad's standard HTML results window, so you can see the value change in place while the main thread is blocked, whereas calling `DumpLive` on an IObservable uses a WPF control to render the updates, so the main thread must remain unblocked in order to see updates as they occur.

It's also possible to dump a WPF or Windows Forms control and update it in place:

```
var txt = new TextBox().Dump();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    txt.Text = i.ToString();
    await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

Just as with `DumpLive`, you must be careful not to block the main thread. If you replaced `await Task.Delay` with `Thread.Sleep`, you'd block the UI thread and nothing would appear until the end.

Comment: it looks like this solution is going to hit the limit of the graph very quickly, maybe I should try the 2nd option

Comment: how come the first short answer doesn't work here? http://share.linqpad.net/ifhso7.linq

Comment: When updating Content to an identical value, no change will be detected. Instead call dc.UpdateContent(...) or call dc.Refresh()

Comment: I worked around it, by setting the content to null between updates, I'll check the recommended methods, thanks.